# View your files, download specific purchased file , protected downloads page

Tags: php

I have a page where user logins , and then it shows all of the files he have purchased.

I want to do so when he clicks on download file button, it will download the file instantly.

**Problem:**

User can simply copy the link and pass it to his friends, and then everyone can download this file.

**Qestion**

How could I protect the downloads so that user can download his files anytime, but others can't, they will have to purchase it first.

***My idea:***

When user clicks on the download link, it will generate a link and then download the file, that link will get deleted after 10 seconds  instantly.

*But I am not to sure if its good enough, not secure or how to do it at all..*

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to verify that the person logged in has rights to that link. Save the ID to a database with that user's ID, then check the user ID against the file ID before allowing the download. Redirect to the login page if they're not logged in, or to an error page if they are, but don't have access.

Comment: What if they find out the real download url? like with the .zip ending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is, instead of giving a "direct" link to the file, proxy it through a PHP script.  Make sure the files are *outside* of the webroot, so that there is no way for them to get a direct link to it.  Your PHP script can access the file, but a web browser cannot.

When the user clicks the link, a script will check if they are logged in or not, and then if they are allowed to access the file or not.  If they can access the file, then send the file (with the correct headers) to the browser, otherwise throw an error.

Something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Figure out if user is logged in and if they can download the file
if($_SESSION['loggedin'] && can_download($file)){
    header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($file));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
else{
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    die('You are not allowed to access this file.'); 
}
```

Comment: WIll try this out! Thanks a lot. Didn't know you can do such thing with headers.

Comment: Yeah, setting the headers can be fun.  You can a PHP script "pretend" to be anything! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the link require a valid logged in session, but that's beside the point and probably isn't going to achieve anything.

If he wants to share the file with his friend, he can just download it and send the file over Skype or upload it on 4Shared. Anything you do, other than implementing some kind of DRM on the file, is not going to prevent the user from sharing it.

Comment: DRM ... the only safe way .. moot point if people can just dl and distribute it.

Comment: But the point is, protect these files from being downloaded directly using the link, I don't really care if they share it through skype. I thought if I set that specific download an ID, and then when user attempts to download, it will check if he has that file, if yes, download

Comment: @user1761494, in that case store the file in db as a blob, create a link on demand only if he's logged in and delete the file after say 10 mins or a few multiple however long it would take to download on a slow connection.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a session ID for users that are logged in, track it in your database and only allow downloads from users that have a matching session ID..

OR

require authentication on the page, only authenticated users can download

OR

when a user purchases/registers have a table that gives them access to specific resources and only allow user ID's with access to the resource to download

OR

use an AJAX link to a page that checks any of the above instead of a direct link, that way you can distribute the link and still perform checks

just a few thoughts.